# What is the etymology of multiplication and division operators?

Tags: terminology

When I was studying mathematics in school, we used to have "x"(cross) as multiplication operator. Consequently, "⋅"(dot) became the multiplication operator, then came "*"(asterick).

Similarly for division I had seen: ÷, / and — (its not minus-read long dash) operators

But I really have no idea of why so much overriding for the same operators. Is there any specific reason of using specific operator for specific operations-for example, fractions generally use — division operator (I have seen ÷ rarely to be used to depict fraction)

Also, I have not seen addition and subtraction operators to be changing so drastically with contexts?

Comment: see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obelus)

Comment: See [Earliest Uses of Symbols of Operation](http://jeff560.tripod.com/operation.html) for detailed informations about the origins of the symbols for *multiplication* and *division*.

Comment: @AndresMejia Your link does answer a bit for division operator..If you find any for multiplication then please share that too :)

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA your link is great-can you summarize here as answer. I will happily accept it. (Links can die in future)

Comment: The site linked is a useful on-line summary of the fundamental book : Florian Cajori, [A History of Mathematical Notations](https://books.google.it/books?id=_byqAAAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover), Dover (original ed 1928). See also [here](https://archive.org/details/historyofmathema031756mbp).